# Windows XP random blue screen

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

The image below is a screenshot of a newly installed version of Windows XP 32 bit Pro.  I keep getting this randomly - usually when I have left the room for a few hours and come back to my PC - and it's died on me!

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Exception

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=329284

Answer (score 1):

It happens when one of your hardware generates unrecoverable error. Please, view [detailed information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329284) on Microsoft site.